# Error INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER without any provider on my app

Tags: android, gradle, google-analytics, google-play-services

I'm getting this error:

> INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER - multiple apps using same
>   authority provider name

But I don't have any provider on my app, then I noticed that the final `AndroidManifest.xml` has the following provider:

```
    <provider
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.google.android.gms.measurement.google_measurement_service"
        android:exported="false" />
```

This seems an [analytics issue](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=784) on the latest Google Play Services library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add an `applicationId` setting on your build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your.package.name"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, The error message you see above happens only when you want to install the same application instance on the same device.

```
flavors {
   prod {
     applicationId "your.package.name.prod"
   }
   qa {
     applicationId "your.package.name.qa"
   }
}
```

From the error message you can clearly identify the issue, which occurred due to provider tag in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

> **Solution:**
>   1. Identify which provider tag is causing the issue.
>   2. Most probably the issue could be android:authroties field. 
>   3. Extend the same provider in your AndroidManifest.xml and add tools:merge="${applicationId}.some.string" field

Basically you should have a unique provider name (android:authroties) in all of your application apks.